# Meshlab Parameterization + Texture from registered rasters crashes every time

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, unreal-engine4, meshlab, photogrammetry

I've been trying to do some photogrammetry using visualsfm and meshlab.

So far, the visualsfm works astoundingly, and can generate point clouds very easily. But meshlab, this is where the problems start flooding in.

I usually start by importing the point cloud, cleaning up the excess vertices, and then go and generate the geometry. Once the geometry has been generated, I go and remove any faces that are abnormal and not what I want, then I issue the remove manifold edges algorithm. Once all of that is done, I try and export both the mesh, and the texture image file which is generated from the photos in which I took. Once I issue the Parameterization + Texture from registered rasters, note that I only ask for a resolution of 2048, it ends up freezing after about 5 seconds of rough GPU usage, and shows (Not Responding).

I do not really know how to fix this problem, I wish to create my own assets in which don't require expensive monthly payments for Pro software (Come on, I'm literally a college student without that kind of funds).

I am running windows 10 1607
Intel I7-7700 3.60 GHZ
16 GB of ram
64 bit

I am using around 140 images, But I have seen other people on youtube use much more without any problems.

If anyone can help me fix this problem, or show me another mesh editing software in which does the same work, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I use VisualSFM for 3D (dense) point reconstruction and import into MeshLab to mesh. You have to open the files in MeshLab correctly. Open MeshLab > Open Project > Open .nvm.cmvs folder and open the folder "00" then click on the 'bundle.rd.out" file and it will go to the list.txt file. Open it, and MeshLab will import all the images. You need to select show vertices button to view (0 Model). Then File > Import Mesh and select the ".nvm.cmvs > models" folder and Shift select all "option-000*.ply files and open them. MeshLab will create a layer for each .ply model. Hide the "0 model" layer and right click on one of the other layers .ply models and select "Flatten Layers" making sure you select "keep unregistered vertices" (bottom checkbox) and deselect "delete layers" otherwise you need to duplicate first and hide. Also make sure all .ply layers are visible. Meshlab will merge the meshes into one mesh. Then you need to check for non-manifold edges & faces & delete any if present, then you can Texture parameterization-texturing from registered rasters and it UV Map the images onto the mesh + create a .png texture UV Map, which you need to save. Hope this helps. Let me know if you need any more info, be glad to help. Cheers.